# What sketching software exists that has minimal memory requirements?

Tags: software-recommendation

I want a software that can make sketches on lubuntu and also has ability to save it.

The program must work in 512 mb or less RAM and thus I cannot use a heavy-weight - memory intensive - solution

Also, I want it for my 10 year old sister who has less knowledge

Answer (score 8):

## **Pencil**

[image: Install via the software center]

> It is for draw cartoons. But it is so easy to use.
>
> Also easy to install.(Around 1 Mb to download).
>
> Also can make animations from drawings.(There is a timeline). That
>   gives a basic skill for Blender.
>
> Can save image in diffrent formats.

```
sudo apt-get install pencil
```

** *If in Ubuntu 12.04 or older:*

```
sudo apt-get install libming1
```

Then install from above link with ***Software Centre***

[image]

To Save the created picture Go to ***File*** *Menu* and select ***Export*** *Option*. Then Select ***Image Sequence***. If you Want to save it as a *Catoon*, select, ***Movie*** or ***Flash/swf*** *Option*.

[image]

Then, if it is a Picture, in Forth-comming ***Export as*** dialog, type file name as `[Filename].png` or `.jpg`

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Try Inkscape.

An Open Source vector graphics editor, with capabilities similar to Illustrator, CorelDraw, or Xara X, using the W3C standard Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) file format.

Inkscape supports many advanced SVG features (markers, clones, alpha blending, etc.) and great care is taken in designing a streamlined interface. It is very easy to edit nodes, perform complex path operations, trace bitmaps and much more. We also aim to maintain a thriving user and developer community by using open, community-oriented development.<sup>[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)</sup>

You can download 0.48.4 from [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/download/?lang=en), or click [**Inkscape** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/inkscape/) to install 0.48.1 from Ubuntu Apps.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to give "Tuxpaint" a shot, you can find it in the Ubuntu Software Center or install it by running the following in a terminal `sudo apt-get install tuxpaint`

If Tuxpaint is a bit too childish for a 12-year old, you could also try GIMP or GNUpaint - both are available at the Ubuntu Software Center as well.

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

There is many paint softwares available in Ubuntu. You can use `Gnome Paint`

, `GNU Paint`, `Tux Paint`, `Kolourpaint` etc. I Use `Kolourpaint`.

[image: Kolourpaint screenshot]
[Download Kolourpaint](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kolourpaint4/)